# Pass tenant id via sql server connection

Tags: sql-server, multi-tenant

I'm building multi tenant application with shared table structure using Microsoft SQL Server.

I wonder if it possible to pass tenantID parameter via sql server connection. I don't want to create separate user account for each tenant.

Currently I see two ways: via ApplicationName or WorkstationID

Best regards,
Alexey Zakharov

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the [Application Name of the connect string](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-connection-string), which is then easy to get at in TSQL with [APP_NAME (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms189770.aspx).

However, you could also consider using [CONTEXT_INFO (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180125.aspx).

```
--to set value
DECLARE @CONTEXT_INFO  varbinary(128)
SET @CONTEXT_INFO =cast('Anything Here!!'+REPLICATE(' ',128) as varbinary(128))
SET CONTEXT_INFO @CONTEXT_INFO


--to use value
IF CAST(CONTEXT_INFO() AS VARCHAR(128))='Anything Here!'
BEGIN
    --do something
END
```